# Webpack creating duplicate entries for dependencies

Tags: javascript, browserify, webpack

I am trying to switch from using browserify to webpack. One thing browserify handled nicely was dependency management inside dependencies. Let me give an example:

Main app project:

```
var util1 = require('shared-components/util1');
var util2 = require('shared-components/util2');
```

Inside shared-components/util1.js

```
var util2 = require('../util2');
```

Browserify would realize that the reference to util2 in both scenarios was the same but it appears that Webpack does not which creates duplicate entries for util2.

Is there a configuration setting or plugin I can use to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()`. See [the docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#deduplication) for more info.