# Does webpack bundle equal peer dependencies multiple times?

Tags: webpack

Let's say I create an npm package called `react-web-component` that uses and imports `react-dom`, like so:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default {
  create: function (app, tagName, options) {
    // Some code
    ReactDOM.render(app, mountPoint);
  }
};
```

I would publish it on npm as `react-web-component`;

Now I create a second project that uses `webpack` and `react` and all the other good stuff and I would use my own npm package like so:

***package.json***

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-web-component": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
}
```

***index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactWebComponent from 'react-web-component';
import App from './App';

ReactWebComponent.create(<App />, 'my-react-web-component');
```

Woud `webpack`, when it bundles the application bundle `ReactDom` twice or once? And of the answer is twice, is there any chance to get my project to bundle `ReactDom` only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using a relatively recent version (webpack 2 or later) of webpack, it seems it will automatically detect and remove the duplicate (i.e. bundle it only once), and for older versions it can be done manually with `--optimize-dedupe` or  `new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()`.

Sources: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#deduplication

[Webpack creating duplicate entries for dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412009/webpack-creating-duplicate-entries-for-dependencies)

Also, it appears Zillow has created a tool to detect duplicate dependencies with different versions, which can sometimes be optimized to use the same version, that tool is here: https://github.com/zillow/webpack-stats-duplicates

Source:
https://www.zillow.com/engineering/webpack-optimize-dependencies/

Comment: @AJStacy is this answer acceptable for the bounty? If not what other information does it need?

Comment: For anyone bumping into this issue with Webpack 4: The dedupe plugin has been deprecated. This is still an issue for a lot of people https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5593